# Deleting and undeleting an answer clears the edit history

Tags: support, edits, deleted-answers

I posted [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3071247/1508) to a question. The question was then edited by a roving well-wisher, which invalidated my answer. So I edited the question to reflect this, and deleted my answer.

The original question was subsequently restored, thus re-validating my answer. So I undeleted my answer. But when I went to revert the edit, my original answer was nowhere to be found! It seems that deleting and undeleting an answer clears its edit history.

Is this intentional, or a bug? Or is it just that retaining the edit history would be difficult to implement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Deletion does not ever clear revision history.

What happened is that you edited your post within the 5-minute grace period, which overrides the current revision rather than creating a new one. There never was a history on your answer. This is one reason why you really shouldn't edit your answers to be useless messages like "no longer relevant" - the grace period might actually lose your work entirely.

Comment: If an answer becomes invalid, because of an edit to a question, you should simply delete the answer.